# concatenate all files returned by wiredep into one single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Every time I install any dependency using bower is including all my dependencies into my `index.html` this is perfect!

> **The problem:**

It's returning all my files separately causing to many unnecesary HTTP calls. I need to concatenate all my bower dependencies into one file, so I can eventually minify it and apply HTTP compression.

any ideas?

```
var options = {
            bowerJson: config.bower.bowerJson,
            directory: config.bower.directory,
            ignorePath: config.bower.ingnorePath
        };

    gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
        'use strict';
        log('Injectin Bower components into the Layout page');
        var options = config.getWiredConfiguration();
        var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

        return gulp
        .src(config.layout + 'index.cshtml')
        .pipe(wiredep(options))
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src('js/layout/layout.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.layout));
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

It's a quite old question, but I have a solution which works for me and should work for the others.

Firstly, we have to understand how *wiredep* works. It's not as obvious as I thought before, because *wiredep* by default operates on a file **to which** you are injecting. A typical implementation is as follows:

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

gulp.task('bower', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/footer.html')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            ignorePath: '../'
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```

Take a look at the *require* part, where the *stream* function is assigned to a *wiredep* variable. Since this moment, you are using only the *stream* function which in fact does not return a stream of bower components as you may thought. *wiredep* now operates on a file passed to pipe, which in the above example is *footer.html* and the output of the pipe will still be *footer.html*, but modified by *wiredep*. That's why you end up with *all.js* containing an *index.cshtml*. It is a pipe chaine like below:

```
                    bower_components
                           |
                           V
"src/footer.html" ===> wiredep.stream() ===> gulp.dest() ===> "dest/footer.html"
```

At this point, we should ask two questions: how to obtain a list of files which *wiredep* uses and how to use them. Thankfully, there are answers to them.

## How to obtain a list of files

It's a rather simple task. Firstly, modify the *require* function call to include the whole library: `var wiredep = require('wiredep');`. Since then, you can use two additional fields provided by *wiredep*: `wiredep().js` - get JS files from *bower_components*, `wiredep().css` get CSS files from *bower_components*.

## How to use them

To finish this task, I use **gulp-inject** which is perfect for this kind of jobs, and of course **gulp-concat**. If you don't have then, just install them by NPM (`npm install --save-dev gulp-inject gulp-concat`) and add a dependency to your *gulpfile*.

If your example *index.html* looks as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

Your *gulpfile* will look something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');

gulp.task('bower', injectBower);

function injectBower() {
    var target = gulp.src('./html/index.html');
    var js = gulp.src(wiredep().js);
    var css = gulp.src(wiredep().css);

    return target
        .pipe(inject(js.pipe(concat('bower.js')).pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts'))))
        .pipe(inject(css.pipe(concat('bower.css')).pipe(gulp.dest('./styles'))))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./html'));
}
```

And now, after you run `gulp bower`, your *index.html* should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bower.css"/>
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="scripts/bower.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

Gulp will create the concatenated JS file in the `scripts` directory and the concatenated CSS file in the `styles` directory. You can freely customize this process; for more information, visit the [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) page. *gulp-inject* is quite flexible tool, thus you should be able to achieve expected results. In my case, I have also *gulp-uglify* and *gulp-rev* appended when building the production environment.

If you have any questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [gulp concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat)

This will be the next step in your gulpfile.js

```
var options = {
            bowerJson: config.bower.bowerJson,
            directory: config.bower.directory,
            ignorePath: config.bower.ingnorePath
        };

gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    'use strict';
    log('Injectin Bower components into the Layout page');
    var options = config.getWiredConfiguration();
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

    return gulp
    .src(config.layout + 'index.cshtml')
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src('js/layout/layout.js')))
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.layout));
});
```

Or maybe a seperate scripts task:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Comment: if I take that aproach then I would have to manually remove all the tags from ` <!-- bower:css --> <!-- endbower -->`

Comment: I recommend try it and let me know what happens. (don't manually remove anything and backup first) :) I'm using grunt with concat, and I didn't have to remove bower comments. Should work the same I hope.

Comment: I try it... but now is not hitting the file to write it

Comment: I did change my code one time. Make sure our code is the same. Anyway, it didn't create `all.js` anywhere at all?

Comment: it created a new all.js file... but is basically a duplicate od the index.cshml with a .js extension

Comment: ok well `concat` definitely combines files, so you might want to check its documentation to see what needs to adjust. My answer isn't 100% correct then, but I'll keep it b/c I think I'm on the right track. You can then do [gulp-usemin](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin) to put the right references back into index.html

Comment: @stwissel, I'm no longer on that project. I don't think there's a way for me to get back to the code and check. Sorry.

Comment: Thx anyway. The quest for the perfect gulp script remains elusive